# GNU Make expand pattern within shell command

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a situation where I need a small program to determine the prerequisites of a file by examining it. Concretely:

```
%.bar: $(shell python get_preqs.py %.foo) # % in shell is not substituted
    python gen_bar.py $^ $@
```

This doesn't work however, as the `%` in the shell command doesn't get substituted in by make. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [.SECONDEXPANSION feature](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) of GNU make:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.bar: $$(shell python get_prereqs.py $$*.foo)
        python gen_bar.py $^ $@
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a build tool more suited to dynamic targets.  For example, I've written a Gnu Make-like tool incorporating some of the concepts from DJB's ReDo, called [GoodMake](https://github.com/AmesCornish/GoodMake).  Your equivalent makefile would just be:

```
#? *.bar
    preqs=$(python get_preqs.py ${1%.bar}.foo)
    $0 $preqs
    python gen_bar.py $preqs $1
```